# Is using <article> inside <form> semantically fine?

Tags: html, semantic-ui

Like the below html.
I want to use article as its main content of the form.
I've already used a main element on the outside of the form element by the way.

```
<form>
  <header>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <button type="submit">Close</button>
  </header>
  <article>
    <fieldset>
      <legend></legend>
      <input />
      <input />
      <input />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend></legend>
      <input />
      <input />
    </fieldset>
  </article>
</form>
```

Comment: From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) permitted content ***flow content*** which includes ***article***-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

A semantic tag is simply an element that defines itself semanticly to the developer. Using an `<article>` tag is no different than using a block level element such as a `<div>` tag except it is semantically sound.

The  tag specifies independent, self-contained content.

**What are Semantic Elements?**

A semantic element clearly describes its meaning to both the browser and the developer.

Examples of non-semantic elements: `<div>` and `<span>` - Tells nothing about its content.

Examples of semantic elements: `<form>`, `<table>`, and `<article>` - Clearly defines its content.

**ASP.NET**

In the case of asp.net web forms if the tag was not allowed then it couldn't be used at all as the entire structure must be encased in a `<form>` tag.

**W3 Schools Documentation**

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp

Answer (score 1):

I wont use it in that way, because you should use the tags that are semantically appropriate for a given task or content.

**Definiton:** *The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication.*

So article must be a single piece of content that can stand on its own. If a piece of content can be republished on another site without being modified, or if it can be pushed out as an update via RSS, or on social media sites such as Twitter or Facebook.

**Usage:**

- a forum post
- a blog entry
- a magazine or newspaper article
- a user-submitted comment on a blog entry or article